# Borel Set Example.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

In terms of this definition, I still struggle very much with how the *Borel $\sigma$-Algebra* is directly related to a Borel Set. Perhaps an example demonstrating how they are directly related? I always see the term B($\mathbb R$) thrown around, but I still don't see a clear connection between that and the Borel Sets! A Borel Set is an element of the *Borel $\sigma$-Algebra*, if that's the case then what does the *Borel $\sigma$-Algebra* look like? B($\mathbb R$)= ?

> **Definition**:
>
> The *Borel $\sigma$-algebra* on $\mathbb R$ is the *$\sigma$-algebra* B($\mathbb R$) generated by the $\pi$-system $\mathcal J$ of intervals $\ (a, b]$, where $\ a<b$ in $\mathbb R$ (We also allow the possibility that $\ a=-\infty\ or \ b=\infty$) Its elements are called *Borel sets*.
> For A $\in$ B($\mathbb R$), the $\sigma$-algebra
> $$B(A)= \{B \subseteq A: B \in B(\mathbb R)\}$$
> of Borel subsets of A is termed the *Borel* $\sigma$-algebra on A.

Comment: @Did , hi please un-duplicated my question i have edited it :)

Comment: Your edit after the question was marked as duplicate reduces to this: "A Borel Set is an element of the _Borel σ-Algebra_ , if that's the case then what does the _Borel σ-Algebra_ look like? B(ℝ)= ?" To that the answer is clear: Yes, B(ℝ) denotes the Borel σ-algebra.

Comment: @Did , sorry so i now know that B(ℝ) is full of Borel Sets! (well kinda) but what does the B(ℝ) look like B(ℝ)={ {borel set 1.},{borel set 2.},{borel set 3.}, ...} perhaps there is a misunderstanding that ive made?

Comment: Once again, B(ℝ) is defined as the set of Borel subsets of ℝ. This is its *definition*. No idea where you are heading to.

Comment: To talk about "look like" - first, is that clear to you how $2^\Bbb R$ (the collection of all subsets of $\Bbb R$) looks like? If so, $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ is just its subcollection that only contains "good" sets: open sets, closed sets, their intersection and unions etc. Since "good sets" is slightly ambiguous, we say "Borel sets". Of course you can *start* writing $\mathcal B(\Bbb R) = \{B_1,B_2,B_3,\dots\}$ for example $\mathcal B(\Bbb R) = \{[2,4], (\pi,7),(-10,\frac12),\dots\}$ however there are not enough natural numbers to finish this enumeration.

Comment: @Ilya ah by "good sets" you mean sets that carry the properties of "open sets, closed sets, their intersection and unions etc."?  (which is a borel set of course) your answer is what ive been searching for thank you! and i am aware of the power set!